# How to access chrome history from android api 25+?

Tags: android

since the normal permission was removed in kitkat, I find it really hard to find any information.

I want to access the default installed chrome browser's history in android oreo or around that version

Comment: Did you find any work around? Please let me know. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is not possible anymore since Android 6 Marshmallow.
The [release note](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser) tells us :

> **Browser Bookmark Changes**
>
> This release removes support for global bookmarks. The android.provider.Browser.getAllBookmarks() and android.provider.Browser.saveBookmark() methods are now removed. Likewise, the READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS and WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS permissions are removed. If your app targets Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, don't access bookmarks from the global provider or use the bookmark permissions. Instead, your app should store bookmarks data internally.

It was once reported as a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=544365) but as `comment 2` says, it is deprecated